# Let $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/n}$ Prove that $x^n -1 =(x-1)(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^2) \dots (x-\zeta^{n-1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclotomic-polynomials

This is a question about cyclotomic polynomials and I have already shown that $x^n-1 =\Pi\Phi_d(x)$, taking the product over all divisors d of n.

Comment: Each $\zeta^m$ satisfies the polynomial $x^n-1=0$, so $(x-\zeta^m)$ must be a linear factor.  I think that's all there is to it

Comment: Uh, how is $\Phi_d(x)$ defined there... ?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein cyclotomic polynomial, the minimal polynomial of a primitive d-th root of unity.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I think that as usual: the product of the different *primitive* linear factors of $\;x^n-1\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc that definition makes this problem trivial. That's why I was asking.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein Yes, trivial...for whoever knows all the little things around this. Obviously not for the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Each of $\zeta^j$ for $j=0, \dots,  n-1$ is a root of $X^n -1$. Thus $(X-\zeta^j)$ must divide it. Since all the $\zeta^j$ are distinct, the linear factors are co-prime and thus the product divides $X^n - 1$ too.

As the degree of both is $n$ and they are both normed, equality follows.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1) Show that for $\;1\le j,\,k\le n\;,\;\;\zeta^j=\zeta^k\iff j=k\;$

2) Show that $\;\left(\zeta^k\right)^n=1\;,\;\;\forall\,k=1,2,...,n\;$

3) Show that all the roots of $\;x^n-1\;$ are different

There you go...